# Where is SF Mono font?

Tags: ios, fonts, ios10

I'm looking at the video of [WWDC 2016 Session 803](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/803/), *Typography and Fonts*.

The video spends quite a lot of time talking about a font called *SF Mono*, the third member of the [San Francisco font family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(2014_typeface)), showing it off in different weights and character sets. Sounds great. I'm ready to use it in the iOS 10 version of my app.

There's just one problem: Where is it? It doesn't seem to be included in iOS itself, and when I [download San Francisco from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), it isn't included there either. I know I could pull a copy out of Xcode 8 itself and include that in my app, but surely that isn't the intended approach. What am I missing?

(Not a duplicate of [What is the NSFont name for the font 'SF Mono'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890778/what-is-the-nsfont-name-for-the-font-sf-mono). He’s talking about NSFont name. I’m talking about the location of the physical font file, such as a *.ttf*. that I can include in an iOS app.)

Comment: I'll have to sit down and watch the whole video, but are you sure the Apple engineer said that the font was available on iOS?  If I recall, the font is only available through Xcode's DVTKit framework.

Comment: I opened [rdar://28467249](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5016548930486272) last week but it was closed as a dupe of an existing open issue.  Did you open one Matt?

Comment: @JAL It wasn't I. Thanks for doing that, though; duplicates, though frustrating, are important.

Comment: Interesting.  According to open radar there are a few other tickets that were opened.  The duplicate target [rdar://26790072](http://www.openradar.me/26790072) appears to be a macOS enhancement rather than an iOS one.  I've asked Apple for more information.

Comment: Just an update: Apple got back to me about closing this iOS bug/enhancement as a dupe of the macOS one.  They said that progress on the iOS work relies on the macOS ticket. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks for the update, @JAL. This is so nutty. Why did they gas on and on about this font if there is no font?

Comment: This could be an help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890778/what-is-the-nsfont-name-for-the-font-sf-mono

Comment: I asked about this again at WWDC this year.  While I was told that the radar comments are private, there is some sort of legal issue with releasing the font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the NSFont name for the font 'SF Mono'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890778/what-is-the-nsfont-name-for-the-font-sf-mono)

Comment: @VolkerE. no it isn’t.

Answer (score 1):

SF Mono can be downloaded from the [Fonts for Apple Platforms](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) page.

Answer (score 0):

I've read this which makes me believe we can't use the SF Mono font in an iOS app.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/82166

**However**, iOS 15 brings in markdown with:

```
Text("`Monospaced`")
```

So you can monospace that way or use the modifier:

```
.monospaced()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/monospaced()