# What is the NSFont name for the font 'SF Mono'?

Tags: swift, nsfont

A new font titled 'SF Mono' was introduced with Xcode 8.

It's a font that I personally find very readable, and I would like to use it in a `NSTextView`. However, to set a font for an `NSTextView`, it is required to use an `NSFont` object. The problem is that I cannot seem to find the `SF Mono` font in the list of available fonts through `NSFontManager.shared().availableFonts`.

Does anyone know what the `SF Mono`'s programmatic name is for the initialisation of an NSFont (`NSFont(name: String, size: CGFloat)`) for its typeface?

Comment: Same question for iOS here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296282/where-is-sf-mono-font. Apparently the font is not available to developers :(

Comment: @MartinR it's not the same question (or at least I don't interpret it to be); I'm looking for the programmatic font name (something like "`.SFNSText`"), but the other question looks for the font file itself. It's a pity it isn't available to developers :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"SF Mono" is not a system font. You cannot select SF Mono outside of Terminal, Console and Xcode because it is not installed to the system.

The "SF Mono" in Terminal is a [**custom font**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680893/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-a-mac-application) in `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts/`.

Similarly, the "SF Mono" in Console is another **custom font** in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts`.

Similarly, the "SF Mono" in Xcode is also a **custom font** in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Resources/`.

And of course you cannot bundle SF Mono alongside your program without violating Apple's copyright license:

> This SF Mono Font (the “Apple Font”) is licensed to you by Apple Inc. (“Apple”) in consideration of your agreement to the following terms. If you do not agree with these terms, do not use the Apple Font.
>
> **You may use the Apple Font solely in conjunction with Apple-branded applications, including, but not limited to, Xcode, Terminal.app and Console.app. You may not embed or use the Apple Font in or with any other software applications or programs or other products** and you may not use the Apple Font to create, develop, display or otherwise distribute any content, documentation, artwork or any other work product.
>
> You may use the Apple Font only for the purposes described in this License or as otherwise expressly permitted by Apple in writing.

If the user has manually installed the font, it can be found with family name **`SF Mono`**, or the font name **`SFMono-Regular`** (similar for the other weights).

```
let f = NSFont(name: "SFMono-Regular", size: 12)
```

Answer (score 12):

With iOS 13 and macOS 10.15 Apple made the new system fonts, including *SF Mono* and *New York*, available for developers.

You can get SF Mono using `NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 0, weight: .regular)`.

Alternatively if you want to use the other system fonts you can use the NSFontDescriptor:

```
if let sfMonoDescriptor = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0).fontDescriptor.withDesign(.monospaced) {
    let sfMonoFont = NSFont(descriptor: sfMonoDescriptor, size: 0)!
}
```

For more information look at the WWDC Session [Font Management and Text Scaling.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/?time=142)